# Storing data directly on chain

Tags: storage, mapping

Im trying to store data directly on the blockchain, not on a smartcountract as they have a limit of what they can handle and it would slow down the chain to go above the limit.

My initial plan is to use mapping but I can't find confirmation if mapping uses available space on the chain or in the smartcontract.

If mapping does store on the smartcontract what functionality can I use to store data directly on the blockchain?

Comment: "directly on the blockchain, not on a smartcountract"??? Be sure you know what you're saying. The only information "not on a smartcontract" is ether balance!

Comment: Well, nonce too...

Comment: Well you can send data in a transaction even if it doesn't go to a contract..

Comment: @LauriPeltonen: Hmmm, interesting... But the transaction will likely revert, unless that data represents an encoded function call, AND that function is viable at the address indicated in the `to` field of the transaction... right?

Comment: Im working on a private chain not the main network so I should be able to store whatever data I want on the blocks I thought

Comment: @goodvibration I don't think so. I think any data is valid, the transaction reverts only when the data is checked against a contract (and fails). But not 100% sure. @ WesternWarrior you still have to obey Ethereum protocols, although in this case I think you're ok

Comment: @LauriPeltonen: First off, regarding the comment above yours, the type of network (private or public) has no impact on the answer to the question at hand. As to your speculation, I'm not sure about it. But I'd expect that if `data == ""` then it's a simple transaction of ether-transfer, while in any other case, `data` must represent an ABI-encoded function call, and that function must be viable on the destination address of the transaction (specified in the `to` field).

Comment: If I understand your speculation correctly, then you're saying that if the destination address is not of a contract, then the transaction would still go through somehow, and the data will be stored somehow (though I don't quite understand where exactly, and in what way would anyone be able to retrieve it).

Answer (score 0):

"Storing data on-chain isn't scalable and Firebase & Postgres aren't decentralized".

Polybase is a horizontally scalable web3 database that understands tokens, wallets & zk. You can use a decentralized database for storing your data off-chain where there are zk proofs generated on-chain.